# Javascript clarification

Tags: javascript

Starting Javascript for the first time. Looking through some notes I found the following code on creating objects.

```
var foo = {};
var bar = new Object();
```

Then:

```
var foo = {
   bar:2
}
```

Could anyone let me know the significance of the :2 after bar? What is it referring to?

PS. Have not tried Javascript before so any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's not referring to anything, `2` is the value of the key `bar`.

Comment: I recommend reading through eloquentjavascript.net/‎, and only then asking questions on basic syntax

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: You have two variables named bar in this example, so that might be what's confusing you. One is an empty object, the other is a property of the "foo" object, and it has a value of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just initializes a object `foo` with the attribute `bar` with the (default) value `2`.
It can be accessed with `foo.bar` and of course set with (for example) `foo.bar = 3`

You can initialize any kind of object with this. For example a `car` object which saves the amount of tires, doors, and the color:

```
var car = {
    amountTires: 4,
    amountDoors: 3,
    color: "red"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that context, bar would be the object's property, and '2' would be it's value.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you mentioned in the question is intended to demonstrate different methods of creating an object.

The first method `var foo = {}` uses the object notation `{}` the second method `var bar = new Object()` uses the `Object` constructor.

Going deeper, the object `foo` is given an attribute `bar` with value `2`. The contents of an object is often specified as key-value pairs.